# stream audio to a sails backend

Tags: sails.js, web-audio-api

I'm trying to stream audio from a browser (via mic) to a server for playback on speakers attached to the computer.

My server code calls getUserMedia(), pulls the left channel (b/c mono input) and sends it via websockets to my server, once every 1024 bytes.

I have an embedded device (think RPi) running node and with a speaker connected. I'd like to somehow take these bytes and stream them to a node server running sails.js, which will then play the audio out of a connected speaker

**Client**

```
function recorderProcess(e) {
    var single = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    io.socket.post('/emit_audio', convertFloat32ToInt16(single), function(){
        console.log('bytes sent');
    });
}
```

**Server**

```
emit_audio: function(req, res) {
    //This is where I get stuck
    sails.log('got bytes');
},
```

I've basically spent all day googling how to get the socket data from sails. The best I could find was to use the req.files() function from sails-skipper, but that requires a string identifier as a parameter. Is getting streaming data possible, or does the ajaxy implementation from sails prevent such a thing?